# "Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING" error despite JSON being valid

Tags: java, json, retrofit

I'm currently working on an end of the semester project. It is an android app that would function as both a music database and shop, and I am using the MusicBrainz API to fetch the information on releases and artists.

Unfortunately, I'm stuck on a very vital part of my project: the API itself. I keep getting this error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
```

Looking around online, I discovered that this was because the JSON itself was badly written, however, looking again and using a JSON validator made me realise that this was not the case. Here is the json I'm trying to fetch

```
{
    "ipis": [],
    "type": "Group",
    "life-span": {
        "end": "2017-02-04",
        "begin": "1969",
        "ended": true
    },
    "area": {
        "name": "United Kingdom",
        "id": "8a754a16-0027-3a29-b6d7-2b40ea0481ed",
        "type": null,
        "disambiguation": "",
        "iso-3166-1-codes": ["GB"],
        "type-id": null,
        "sort-name": "United Kingdom"
    },
    "disambiguation": "",
    "type-id": "e431f5f6-b5d2-343d-8b36-72607fffb74b",
    "isnis": ["0000000123694269"],
    "name": "Black Sabbath",
    "begin_area": {
        "name": "Birmingham",
        "type": null,
        "id": "226c4dca-ef2a-4d4b-ba25-4118d116557a",
        "disambiguation": "",
        "type-id": null,
        "sort-name": "Birmingham",
        "iso-3166-2-codes": ["GB-BIR"]
    },
    "id": "5182c1d9-c7d2-4dad-afa0-ccfeada921a8",
    "gender-id": null,
    "end-area": {
        "name": "Birmingham",
        "id": "226c4dca-ef2a-4d4b-ba25-4118d116557a",
        "type": null,
        "disambiguation": "",
        "type-id": null,
        "iso-3166-2-codes": ["GB-BIR"],
        "sort-name": "Birmingham"
    },
    "begin-area": {
        "name": "Birmingham",
        "type": null,
        "id": "226c4dca-ef2a-4d4b-ba25-4118d116557a",
        "disambiguation": "",
        "type-id": null,
        "sort-name": "Birmingham",
        "iso-3166-2-codes": ["GB-BIR"]
    },
    "country": "GB",
    "sort-name": "Black Sabbath",
    "gender": null,
    "end_area": {
        "name": "Birmingham",
        "id": "226c4dca-ef2a-4d4b-ba25-4118d116557a",
        "type": null,
        "disambiguation": "",
        "type-id": null,
        "iso-3166-2-codes": ["GB-BIR"],
        "sort-name": "Birmingham"
    }
}
```

and here is part of my code:

My main method:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private  static  final String TAG = "Mainactivity";

    JSONPlaceHolderArtist artistJSON;
    Button b;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        artistJSON = MusicBrainzAPI.getClient().create(JSONPlaceHolderArtist.class);
        b = findViewById(R.id.button);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                getArtist();
            }
        });
    }

    private void getArtist() {
        Call<ArtistAPI> call = artistJSON.getArtist("5182c1d9-c7d2-4dad-afa0-ccfeada921a8");
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ArtistAPI>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ArtistAPI> call, Response<ArtistAPI> response) {
                Log.e(TAG,"on response: " + response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ArtistAPI> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i(TAG, "on failure: " + t.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The ArtistAPI class:

```
public class ArtistAPI {

    String id, name, country, begin, end;
    Boolean ended;

    public String getArtistID() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getArtistName() {
    [...]
```

The Retrofit interface:

```
public interface JSONPlaceHolderArtist {

    @GET("/artist/{id}/name?fmt=json")
    Call<ArtistAPI> getArtist(@Path("id") String id);
}
```

and the API:

```
public class MusicBrainzAPI {

    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).
                    addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)).build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Any help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Doin't include links to crap; we assume it is an attempt to give us a virus.  Simplify the JSON and include it in the question.

Comment: sorry about that, fixed.